# "Am Freitag und Sonntag die ganzen Tagen Zeit haben" versus "am Freitag und Samstag Zeit haben"

Tags: difference, grammaticality

If I simply write:

> Am Freitag und Samstag habe ich Zeit.

Is it sufficient to express that I'm free the entire day on both days?

If it does not express that, is the following phrase gramatically correct?

> Am Freitag und Samstag habe ich die ganzen Tagen Zeit.

Comment: _"is the following phrase gramatically correct ?"_ No, it's far from being grammatically correct. And yes, the 1st phrase is correct and sufficient.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "it's *far from* being grammatically correct"? I wouldn't say so. It's just *den ganzen Tag* instead of *die ganzen Tagen*.

Comment: I think it's a question of emphasis. You could say *Am Freitag und Samstag bin ich frei.* -- "I'm free on Friday and Saturday." This would more or less imply that you're free at least most of the time. If you wanted to stress that you'll available the entire time on both days then go with *Am Freitag und Samstag habe ich den ganzen Tag frei.* The English and German seem parallel here, even on the question of using the plural on Tag/Day, so I kinda think you're overthinking this one.

Comment: @Olafant What makes it "far from correct", is that building the plural (which seems to be the OPs misconception and is comprehensible) as _die ganzen Tagen_ is also wrong. Correct plural (and is also applicable) would be _die ganzen Tage_. Thus it should be: _Am Freitag und Samstag habe ich die ganzen Tage Zeit._ Feel free to mention that in your (otherwise good) answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to say is that you have time the whole day on both of the days. So *the whole day* refers to one day instead of *all of the days*.

> Am Freitag habe ich *den ganzen Tag* Zeit und am Samstag habe ich *den ganzen Tag* Zeit.

can be shortened to

> Am Freitag und [am] Samstag habe ich [jeweils] *den ganzen Tag* Zeit.

and you can skip the *jeweils* since it's clear what you mean.

> Am Freitag und Samstag habe ich *den ganzen Tag* Zeit.